# How to lock and unlock folder for specific time in Windows?

Tags: windows

I am using Windows 7 Home Edition 32-bit version. Is there any way I can lock one of my PC folders for a specific time, and after the time period is over, the folder will be unlocked automatically? More specifically, suppose I have a folder in my computer D: drive namely "Games". I want to make it lock down for 22 hours every day, and I want to make it accessible for 2 hours, and then lock it automatically after the 2 hours is over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a batch file that uses the [CACLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113206/cacls-windows-7-full-permissions-local-names) command line tool. Then create a [Task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task) that fires that when desired.

Comment: Could you, please, provide an example of the command usage (considering asker's question)?